# Programming with global variables giving wrong results

Tags: c++

I've been coding for a while in other languages and am pretty proficient, but now I am diving more deeply into C++ and have come across some weird problems that I never had in other languages.  The most frustrating one, which a google search hasn't been able to answer, is with two different code orders.

The background is that I have an array of integers, and a pointer an element in the array.  When I go to print the pointer one method prints correctly, and the other prints nonsense.

An example of the first code order is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main(){
    int *pAry;
    int Ary[5]={2,5,2,6,8};

    pAry=&Ary[3];

    cout<<*pAry<<endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

and it works as expected.  However this simple order wont work for the full project as I want other modules to access pAry, so I thought a global define should work, since it works in other languages.  Here is the example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int *pAry;
void evaluate();

void main(){

    evaluate();
    cout<<*pAry<<endl;

    system("pause");
}

void evaluate(){
    int Ary[5]={2,5,2,6,8};
    pAry=&Ary[3];
}
```

When I use this second method the output is nonsense.  Specifically 1241908....when the answer should be 6.

First I would like to know why my global method isn't working, and secondly I would like to know how to make it work.  Thanks

Comment: int Ary[5] is local to the function evaluate(), whenyou go out of scope, that array is no more

Comment: Ah thank you! That explains it.

Comment: It seems the both methods work fine in 2022!

Answer (score 8):

In the second example, `Ary` is local to the function `evaluate`. When `evaluate` returns, `Ary` goes out of scope, and accessing it's memory region results in undefined behaviour.

To avoid this, declare `Ary` in a scope where it will still be valid at the time you try to access it.

Answer (score 4):

It's not working because your `pAry` is pointing into a local array, which is destroyed when you return from `evaluate()`. That's undefined behavior.

One possible fix is to make your local array static:

```
static int Ary[5]={2,5,2,6,8};
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `evaluate()` function, you're aiming `pAry` at a variable (actually array element) *local* to that function. A pointer can only be dereferenced as long as the object to which it points still exists. Local objects cease to exist when they go out of scope; in this case, this means all elements of `Ary` cease to exist when `evalute()` ends, and thus `pAry` becomes a dangling pointer (it doesn't point anywhere valid).

Dereferncing a dangling pointer gives *undefined behaviour;* in your particular case, it outputs a garbage value, but it might just as well crash or (worst of all) appear to work fine until the program changes later.

To solve this issue, you can either make `Ary` global as well, or make it `static`:

```
void evaluate(){
    static int Ary[5]={2,5,2,6,8};
    pAry=&Ary[3];
}
```

A static local variable persists across function calls (it exists from first initialisation until program termination), so the pointer will remaing valid.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to declare `Ary` with *file scope*.

```
int Ary[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

void print_ary(void); // The void parameter is a style thingy. :-)

int main(void)
{
  print_ary();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void print_ary(void)
{
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (sizeof(Ary) / sizeof(Ary[0]); ++i)
  {
    std::cout << Ary[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

A better solution would be to pass a `std::vector` around to your functions rather than using a global variable.